# Enumerating subsets of a finite set satisfying some disjoint union conditions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, coloring

Take a finite set $A=\{1,...,n\}$, and consider subsets $A_1,...,A_m$ of $A$ of fixed cardinalities $a_1,...,a_m\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, subject to a few conditions of the form $A_{i_0}=A_{i_1}\sqcup A_{i_2}\sqcup ... \sqcup A_{i_t}$. (Here, $i_0$ may appear more than once, see an example below)

What is a good way of enumerating such subsets? I want to code this and I'm not sure how. It seems to me this can be translated into a problem of enumerating colorings of some graph.

---

Example: $A=\{1,2\}$, $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5$ of sizes $1,1,2,1,1$ respectively, subject to:
$A_3=A_1\sqcup A_2$, $A_3=A_4\sqcup A_5$. There are exactly 4 such families of subsets:

- $A_1=A_4=\{1\}$, $A_2=A_5=\{2\}$, $A_3=\{1,2\}$
- $A_1=A_5=\{1\}$, $A_2=A_4=\{2\}$, $A_3=\{1,2\}$
- $A_2=A_4=\{1\}$, $A_1=A_5=\{2\}$, $A_3=\{1,2\}$
- $A_2=A_5=\{1\}$, $A_1=A_4=\{2\}$, $A_3=\{1,2\}$

Comment: So this notation $A_{i_0}=A_{i_1}\sqcup A_{i_2}\sqcup ... \sqcup A_{i_t}$ means "disjoint union" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie that's right

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148155/755